# How to use the substr() function inside preg_replace() function?

Tags: php, regex, html-parsing

This is what I have so far, but whatever I try, my `album-content` won't get truncated with `substr()`.

```
$gallery = preg_replace('/(<div class="album-content">)(.*?)(<\/div>)/e', "'$1' . substr(\"$2\", 0, 50) . '$3'", $gallery);
```

UPDATE:

Turns out my class name was incorrect, and my regex does seem to work.
I only had to do another str_replace() to un-escape the output.

```
$gallery = preg_replace('/(<div class="album-desc">)(.*?)(<\/div>)/e', "'$1' . substr(\"$2\", 0, 50) . '$3'", $gallery);
$gallery = str_replace('\"album-desc\"', '"album-desc"', $gallery);
```

Output before modifying:

```
<a href="..." class="album">
    <div class="album-content"><p class="album-title">Album 1</p>
        <div class="album-desc"><p>This will be truncated by substr().</p></div>
    </div>
    <img src="..." />
</a>
```

Thanks all, anyways!

Comment: please post some before and after content, so we have a better idea of what you want to do.

Comment: You can't use `substr()` as part of the replacement string

Comment: @MathieuImbert It does seem to work now though. See my update.

Comment: @fishbaitfood That's odd. Can you provide a complete test case? With a sample of `$gallery`and the resulting output?

Comment: Updated. Output before modifying. But I've made it more efficient by replacing it with a custom function, which returns the `substr()`.

Comment: **Don't use regular expressions to parse HTML**. You cannot reliably parse HTML with regular expressions. As soon as the HTML changes from your expectations, your code will be broken. See http://htmlparsing.com/php.html for examples of how to properly parse HTML with PHP modules.

Comment: @AndyLester Thanks, I'll definately look into that!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `preg_replace_callback()`

```
$replace = preg_replace_callback('/(asd)f/i', function($matches) {
    $matches[1] = substr($matches[1], 0, 2);

    return $matches[1];
}, 'asdf');
```

[Full documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace-callback.php)

Comment: Thanks! I think I'll be using this in the future.

Answer (score 0):

it'd have to be

```
..., "'$1'" . substr("$2", 0, 50) . "'$3'", ...
```

with the substr "outside" of the string.

Comment: Updated my post, my regex did seem to work. I tried your method anyway, but it didn't work.